# How do I compile .cpp to mex?

Tags: matlab

Super-new to Matlab...
Basically I would only like to run:
https://github.com/panly099/sketchSynthesis
The main .m file is 'image2sketch.m' in the synGUI folder.
But im on windows 7 and not linux, so I've been told I need to compile the remaining .cpp files to mex files in order for it to run.
I assume it has something to do with the Matlab Compiler or coder, but I dont really know how or which .cpp files im supposed to compile in order to run it correctly.
These are the current erros im getting when running 'image2sketch.m':

```
image2sketch
[==================================================
current cluster id: 1
Error using chamferLocate (line 103)
Undefined function 'mex_fitline' for input arguments of type 'struct'.

Error in strokeSampling>(parfor body) (line 71)
        [strokeMatched, curCost] = chamferLocate(img, strokeImg, baseScale, baseAspect,
        threshold);

Error in strokeSampling (line 38)
    parfor j = 1 : length(curRepStrokes)

Error in image2sketch>pushbutton_Bbox_Callback (line 193)
configuration = strokeSampling(edgeSecond, strokeModel,detScale(cateId), 1.1, 1.1, 0.7, 5);

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in image2sketch (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in
@(hObject,eventdata)image2sketch('pushbutton_Bbox_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Caused by:
    Undefined function 'mex_fitline' for input arguments of type 'struct'.

Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: M-files are scripts, they don't need compiling. There might be MEX-files in there, which are compiled and hence platform-specific. You'd need to recompile those for Windows using the MATLAB `mex` command.

Comment: Oh I think I misunderstood the guy who wrote it, apparently Im supposed to compile the .cpp's to mex...the ones in the libs folder: https://github.com/panly099/sketchSynthesis/tree/master/libs, the errors I currently am getting are rather confusing: https://imgur.com/a/Xabd7

Comment: I cannot read the text in those images. Please update your question with this new information, and copy-paste the error messages into the question.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited it now.

Comment: So I tried compiling main.cpp in https://github.com/panly099/sketchSynthesis/tree/master/libs/CLD , but I get the error:  `C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed`

Comment: The error is telling you to compile a MEX-file called  `mex_fitline`. That function is in this directory: https://github.com/panly099/sketchSynthesis/tree/master/libs/fdcm_matlab_wrapper_v0.2 -- There is an M-file `make.m` there, you should probably run that to create the MEX-files.

Comment: This directory here also has a bunch of `.cpp` files: https://github.com/panly099/sketchSynthesis/tree/master/libs/ZPclustering -- They include instructions for compiling at the top, just open the `.cpp` file in a text editor to read the instructions.

Comment: Ok...so im getting the same error I replied to Marcus below when I try to mexify these .cpp's: `mex dist2aff.cpp
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'kernel32.lib'`

Comment: You might need to run `mex -setup` first.

Comment: Yep, already tried that...still get the same error...

Comment: How about `mex -setup CPP`? Also, what compiler do you have installed? This seems like a compiler configuration problem.

Comment: I get CPP not found....I think you are right. When I run mex -setup, I have windows SDK 7.1, Visual Studio 10. Whats the best way to fix this?

Comment: I would start by downloading and installing an updated version of Visual Studio. You can get the Community edition for free. Then run `mex -setup CPP` again. Hopefully that fixes whatever configuration issues you have.

Comment: Ok Ill report back. Thanks for helping me through this disaster

Comment: So I installed VS Community 2017...it didnt change anything though, CPP is still not found. These are the compilers that I can choose from: https://imgur.com/a/cJmkC

Comment: Weird. A 32-bit/64-bit discrepancy? I don't know enough about Windows to help with this, sorry...

Comment: I mean, the original was compiled on linux, so maybe that has something to do with it. Thanks for the help anyways

Answer (score 1):

General answer:
Within Matlab navigate to the folder containing the .cpp file

Run:

```
mex file.cpp -output mex_fitline
```

(replace file.cpp with the actual file name and mex_fitline with the name of the missing function in the m-file (same as in the error msg).
If you have a proper C/C++ compiler installed, and the file.cpp does not require additional files, than this should do the trick.
You might need to do it several times in different folders, until all required mex-files are built.

If you don’t have a compiler, you can download and install the free Visual Studio Community Software which comes with a compiler. After you have installed VS Community, restart your PC and then run mex -setup to tell Matlab [which compiler to use.](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/changing-default-compiler.html)

If you need multiple files file1.cpp file2.cpp etc. the command usually goes like

```
mex file1.cpp file2.lib file3.h... -output mex_name
```

Comment: Actually, no the output file name is determined automatically. If you want to specify it you need the `-output` argument. See this example in the documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html#bu65zqt

Comment: Did I do this right? Im getting an error: https://pastebin.com/mziCrudX

Comment: Is the kernel32.lib located inside the folder with the .cpp file or is this a windows library? Try to put kernel32.lib in line with the other files: mex file1.cpp kernel32.lib -output mex_name